# How do I validate my form before redirecting to another page?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, redirect

I'm creating a register form that I want to be validated before it sends the user to the login.html page.

Is there any way to do that with this code? I want all those fields to be more than 2 characters, right now it's enough to write 2 characters in the `#firstName` field and then it redirects.

```
$('#regForm').on('submit', function() {
        if($('#firstName, #lastName, #address, #city, #zip, #phoneNumber, #email, #inputPassword, #confirmPassword').val().length >= 2)
    {
        window.location.replace("login.html");
    } else {
        alert('You must fill in all the required fields.')
    }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.preventDefault()` in callback function:

```
$('#regForm').on('submit', function(event) {

   event.preventDefault();

   if($('#firstName, #lastName, #address, #city, #zip, #phoneNumber, #email, #inputPassword, #confirmPassword').val().length >= 2)
   {
      window.location.replace("login.html");
   } 
   else {
      alert('You must fill in all the required fields.');
   }
});
```

Comment: It still redirects after putting more than 2 characters into the #firstName field while the other fields are empty.

Comment: check one by one: 
`$('#firstName').val().length >= 2 && $('#lastName').val().length >= 2 &&...`

Comment: Tried to check one by one now and still doesn't work, now I just have to click the submit button to be redirected without even filling any field.

Comment: Try `console.log($('#firstName').val())` each input to check the current value? And to prevent redirect just comment `//window.location.replace("login.html");`

Comment: The value that shows is the amount of characters I put in. I want the page to send me to login.html when every field has atleast 2 characters :)

Comment: so this if statement should work fine:
`if ($('#firstName').val().length >= 2 && $('#lastName').val().length >= 2 && $('#address').val().length >= 2 && $('#city').val().length >= 2 &&  $('#zip').val().length >= 2 $('#phoneNumber').val().length >= 2 && $('#email').val().length >= 2 $('#inputPassword').val().length >= 2 && $('#confirmPassword').val().length >= 2)`

Comment: Thanks! I must've missed something earlier maybe, this works fine. Appreciate the help! :)